# ShowDependents shows arrows with ScreenUpdating = False

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

This code will flash an arrow for a brief moment if the ActiveCell has a dependent cell (i.e. another cell has a formula pointing to ActiveCell).
This is unexpected, considering the `ScreenUpdating = False` statement.

```
Public Sub ShowDependents()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveCell.ShowDependents
    ActiveCell.Parent.ClearArrows
End Sub
```

I guess this is a bug in Excel, but it is really annoying - it means we can't use ShowPrecedents/NavigateArrow due to the poor user experience.

Any ideas if there is a way around this - to use ShowDependents without any arrows showing?

This is in Excel 2016, I haven't tested with other versions.

(Note that the simplified code doesn't actually do anything useful, except for showing the problem)

EDIT: Haha! I (sort of) solved it!
Instead of calling ClearArrows, I use

```
ShowDependents Remove:=True
```

and no flashing arrows :-)

The modified code below finds the first dependent cell and sets focus back to the original cell. It still doesn't do anything useful, but it shows it is possible to avoid the flashing arrow.

Now there is still a tiny bit of flickering when I call the sub. No arrows in sight, just a flicker. Probably acceptable but annoying so feel free to give ideas on how to solve that part :-)

```
Public Sub ShowDependents()
Dim source As Range, Target As Range
Set source = ActiveCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

source.ShowDependents
Set Target = source.NavigateArrow(False, 1) ' Will set focus on dependent cell
source.Worksheet.Activate                   ' Reset focus to selected cell
source.ShowDependents Remove:=True          ' ClearArrows will flash arrow
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it in Excel 2010, this problem does not occure for me.

Comment: Doesn't repro for me (Excel 2016).

Comment: @jkpieterse @UGP are you sure? To test this, you need to put a formula like `=A1` into cell B1 then select A1 and run the procedure in the question **step-by-step** (using F8). This is definitely reproducible and definitely shows the referencing arrows (at least in Excel 2016) as stated by the OP. You won't see it if you don't do it the way I explained: e.g if there is no reference to the selected cell or if you don't run step-by-step (because of `.ClearArrows`).

Comment: Running a proc step-by-step tends to turn screenupdating back on. It is a different experience from running at full speed. That being said, I do have the experience that various versions of Excel misbehave with ScreenUpdating. All you can do is turn it off in places where it appears to turn itself back on again.

Answer (score 0):

Just avoid using `.ShowDependents`. You can use `.NavigateArrow` without showing the arrows by using `.Dependents` so you even don't need to deactivate `.ScreenUpdating`.

```
Public Sub ShowDependents()
    ActiveCell.Dependents.NavigateArrow True, 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I should have mentioned that I need to be able to track dependents on other sheets. 
ActiveCell.Dependents.NavigateArrow only works on the same sheet.

Comment: Yes, that's true `.Dependents` doesn't support remote references. But then `.ShowDependents` is the only way to achieve this. And I don't think there is a workaround to hide the arrows then.

Comment: I think you are right, although I am still hoping that somone proves you (and me) wrong :-)

I wonder why MS has made it so hard to handle dependencies.

Comment: Perhaps you can simply select a different sheet prior to issuing the showdependents command?